# “What about” vs. ”what of”

Tags: word-choice, differences, legalese

Example from page 75 of Frederick Schauer’s *Thinking Like a Lawyer*:

> But **what of** mandatory authorities? Are they as “binding” as the traditional
>   terminology suggests? The answer depends on what is meant by
>   “binding,” and it turns out that speaking of “binding” authority can be
>   just as misleading as speaking of “persuasive” authority.

What are the similarities and differences between *what about* and *what of*? I see that the [definitions](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/what) below are worded differently, but I don’t see any intrinsic differences — which I still suspect must exist.

> **what about**
>   1a. does that include (someone) : how about (someone)
>   1b. how does that affect (someone or something) :
>   2. used to make a suggestion about what could be done
>   3. used to ask someone to tell you something in response to the thing that you have just said
>
> **what of** 
>   1. *formal* how does that affect (someone or something)
>   2. why does (something) matter

Answer (score 2):

*What of* and *what about* are not idioms; they don't mean something other than the sum of their parts. To contrast *what of* with *what about* is contrasting *of* and *about*. Are they perfectly synonymous? Some say there are no perfect synonyms. But for all intents and purposes, in this use, *what of* and *what about* are interchangeable.

[Of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/of):

> about; *concerning*.

[About](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/about):

> *concerning*; on the subject of; in regard to.

Though *speak to me of love* sounds poetic, it means, basically, *speak to me concerning love* or *about* love.

> - Obama spoke *of* the need to reduce America's health care costs...
> - President Obama spoke *about* the need for comprehensive immigration reform...

Answer (score 1):

> what of 1. *formal*

That's the difference - 'what of' is formal, 'what about' isn't. The latter is far, far more common in everyday usage.